# lift autocomplete change page content

Tags: autocomplete, lift, widget

im using an auto complete widget to show required inputs to the user in a liftScreen. i need to change the content of the page with the selected option of the autocomplete.

Is it possible with autocomplete widget?

If it is please post an example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of Autocomplete and Ajax:

```
/*Create a ValueCell to update*/
val cell = ValueCell("")

/* Do a basic ajaxText */
val nameAjax = SHtml.ajaxText(cell.get, s=>{ cell.set(s); Noop})

/* Make attributes out of it */
val attrs: Seq[(String,String)] = nameAjax.attributes.toList.map{md => (md.key,md.value.text)}

/* Do the basic autocomplete with your attibutes */
def query(s:String):List[String] /*Do the query to get the desired autocomplete values */
def buildQueryName(current: String, limit: Int): Seq[String] = {
  if (current.length == 0) Nil
  else query(current).take(limit) /*query representing
}
private def processResult(s : String) {}

/* Function to render the autocomplete box */
def autoCompleteBox = AutoComplete("", buildQueryName _, processResult _ , attrs:_* )

/* function to render the dynamic part */
def dynamicPart = WiringUI.apply(cell)(createDynamicPart)

def createDynamicPart(value:String)(ns:NodeSeq):NodeSeq ={
  <h3> value selected: {value} </h3>
}
```